# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Este error me sale cuando intento conectar flutter con la base de datos firebase, ya hice todos los datos y verifique con la documentación de google y también con este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGrNobR60TA.
Ya he intentado varias cosas y nada que conecta, y necesito que conecte para poder hacer una sincronización de datos
Este es mi pubspec.yaml:

```
name: sincro
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: 
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.11
  firebase_auth:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
```

El build.gradle de android:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'    
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Y el buid.grade de android/app:

```
 def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sincro"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
}
```

Si quieren ver todo el codigo esta en el github: https://github.com/Nikolasito/Flutter-Firebase

Comment: intentaste usar flutter clean y luego un flutter pub get

Comment: coincido con diego y tambien te recomendaria solo por las dudas quitar el then() al initializeApp() y dejarlo con await Firebase.initializeApp(); para luego en la siguiente linea usar el runApp()

Comment: Otro detalle, quita el google-services.json de tu github ya que si tienes appcheck de firebase o buenas reglas de seguridad pueden atacar tu backend de firebase (pasa el repo a private)